# How to find a file using a variable for 'Starts with' in Java

Tags: java, file, variables, startswith

I'm trying to find a file based on a variable from an excel sheet. Whenever i use the code below i get the error message "Local variable CaseID defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". I'm still new so i'm not sure how to fix this even though it sounds like a simple fix.

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Z246379\\Documents\\Test beds");
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
 public boolean accept (File dir, String name) { 
   return name.startsWith(CaseID); //the error is on CaseID
} 
 }; 
 String[] children = dir.list(filter);
 if (children == null) {
  System.out.println("Either dir does not exist or is not a directory"); 
 } else { 
  for (int i=0; i< children.length; i++) {
   String filename = children[i];
   System.out.println(filename);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mainForm:comprehensive']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Z246379\\Documents\\Test beds\\" + filename);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Exactly as it says, to use `CaseID` (which by the way should really be `caseId`) in the anonymous class, it must be final or effectively final (i.e. only assigned once). You haven't shown how `caseId` is created so I can't say what you need to change to make that happen...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include those.

  String CaseID = Sheet1.getRow(2).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();

Comment: Show all your code - if that were the only line on which `caseId` was assigned to you would not receive that error...

Comment: ok thanks! i uploaded the full code here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542935/how-to-find-a-file-using-a-variable-for-startswith-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can only access final objects in anonymous classes instances. To understand why this is the case, let's look at what would have happened if this were not the case.

Inner anonymous class instances can remain in memory even after the method in which they were created has returned. Local variables go out of scope when a method returns. This would be problematic if your method returns earlier. So, to avoid this dependence on the local variables, the anonymous class instance actually uses a copy of the local variables. Since, we use copies, it doesn't matter if the original get destroyed.

But here comes another problem. Since we are using copies, if you change the value of the local variable, it won't be reflected in the anonymous class instance. This can cause some really unexpected behaviors and can be confusing.

So we simply use final variables to solve this issue. Starting from Java8 there is also the concept of 'implicitly final' variables. So you don't need to explicitly write final every time. Google this if you're on Java8. But in general, it is best to be explicit when something is final.